# infinite scroll - check if enabled on a container

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using Paul Irish's infinite-scroll jquery package -- https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

I'd like to check if infinite-scroll has already been enabled on a node.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Try `console.log($node.data())` and see if there is anything related to the plugin.

Comment: thanks so much. that is exactly what i needed.  there's an `infinitescroll` object, that contains `options`

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a hack... but if you call `$(selector).infinitescroll('scroll')`, it should return something like `["math:", 6998, 3813]` if it has infinite scroll, and return nothing if it doesn't.

Comment: @JasonP's response had all the info i needed!